# In a Boltzmann machine, why isn't there a simple expression for the optimal edge weights in terms of correlations between variables?

Tags: machine-learning, markov-chain-montecarlo, restricted-boltzmann-machine

Suppose I have a fully connected, fully visible [Boltzmann machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_machine) (no hidden variables) with binary variables $x_i\in \{+1, -1\}$ that defines the probability distribution

$$
p(\mathbf{x} ; \mathbf{W},\mathbf{b}) = \frac{1}{Z} \exp \left( \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{W} \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{b} \right)
$$

and want to choose edge weights $\mathbf{W}$ and bias $\mathbf{b}$ to maximise the likelihood of observing a set of training data. If we do this by using gradient ascent on the log-likelihood function, each step of gradient ascent involves an expensive expectation estimate using MCMC (or some cheaper approximation).

Conceptually the edge weights represent the "interaction strength" between variables, i.e. $w_{ij}$ represents how much $x_i$ and $x_j$ "want" to be equal. Just looking at the above we can see that when $w_{ij}$ is large and positive, $x_i$ and $x_j$ have a high probability of being equal and the when it's negative they have a higher probability of being opposite sign.

What is the relationship between the empirical correlation between each $x_i$ and $x_j$ versus the optimal edge weight $w_{ij}$? It would make sense that variables that are highly positively correlated have large positive edge weights, and variables that are negatively correlated have negative edge weights. But this would imply that learning the edge weights is easy, because we could just calculate the correlations, apply some mapping and get the edge weights. Obviously that is not true or we wouldn't need the expensive algorithm.

Why isn't there a simple expression for the optimal edge weights in terms of the correlations between each pair of variables?

Comment: You seem to be implying that using the energy function above along with gradient descent makes it a Boltzmann machine.  It's not.  That energy function is the same energy function as you would have for logistic regression and basic neural networks.  Boltzmann machines are distinguished by their learning algorithm, which is contrastive divergence.

Comment: Hmm, I am going by the set up in _Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms_ (Mackay 2005) Ch. 43, which doesn't mention CD explicitly (but explains the same basic algorithm for learning).

Comment: If you just minimize the energy by gradient descent, you are describing an autoencoder with no hidden layers — not a Boltzmann machine.

Answer (score 0):

Latent variables are inferred and you can't calculate correlations between their unknown configurations and the input variable configurations.

Without latent variables, if two variables are correlated there is a persistent weight increase in the wake phase, but the balancing sleep phase could do anything depending on weights between other nodes and their configurations.  I don't see how you would analytically solve for the weight's final values.

Comment: I am talking about the fully-visible version without hidden variables.

Comment: @andrew: updated.

Comment: What do you been by wake phase and sleep phase when there are no hidden variables?

Comment: @Andrew: The parameters in a Boltzmann machine are updated by contrastive divergence.  Even without latent variables, you need to let the Markov chain drift in "a sleep phase" whereby the variables take on simulated values based on their neighbors' driven values and edge weights.

Comment: Thanks, I know what you mean now. I am still not sure why the intuition about correlated variables having positive weights is wrong. We are trying to choose weights so the "sleep phase" generates samples that have the same correlations between variables as in training set, and from the expression for p(x) above it seems like this would happen if we choose weights to somehow related to the empirical correlations (intuitively this would mean when we run MCMC in the sleep phase variables with positive edge weights match, etc).

Comment: @andrew: that's interesting to me :)  It's as if you're "rolling the ball down in energy space constraining it to dimensions that preserve the correlations."